# basis of monoid of integral vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, integer-programming, monoid, convex-cone

Suppose that $M\in\mathbb{Z}^{n\times k}$ is a matrix of rank $k<n$. How can I obtain a set of vectors $b_1,\ldots,b_k\in\mathbb{Z}^k$ (if exists) such that each row of $M$ is a non-negative integral linear combination of the $b_i$? For instance, if $M=\begin{pmatrix}2\\3\end{pmatrix}$, I want $b_1=(1)$.
I assume that this is a computationally difficult question. I would be happy if someone can point me to a software. I don't know how to do this with $\texttt{4ti2}$.

Comment: cross-post on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/450547/basis-of-monoid-of-integral-vectors

Comment: Do you mean $b_i\in \mathbb{Z}^k$ rather than $b_i\in\mathbb{Z}^n$?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks!

Comment: The [Smith normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form) seems relevant, in particular if $M = SDT$ with $D$ diagonal and $S, T$ invertible then you want the non-zero rows of $DT$.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not preserve non-negativity.